# Reading from file in C Error

Tags: c

I am trying to read values from a file line by line and print them.. and the output is that it prints the last line twice.. Why would it do this being that the last line is the end of the file?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned long long address;
    int rv = fscanf(file, "%lli", &address);
    printf("%lli\n", address);
    do{
        rv = fscanf(file, "%lli", &address);
        printf("%lli\n", address);
    } while (rv!=EOF);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `"%llu"`, not `"%lli"`, to read an `unsigned long long` value. (Unlike `"%lli"`, neither `"%lld"` nor `"%llu"` supports hexadecimal and octal; there doesn't seem to be a good solution for that.)

Comment: `if (file == NULL){perror(argv[1]);return 1;}`

Answer (score 4):

You don't check if the "inside" `fscanf` actually succeeded. If you're at the end of the file, it WON'T read anything, `&address` doesn't get updated, and `rv` gets `0` for bytes read.

Then you unconditionally print out whatever's in `address`, which happens to be whatever you did successfully read last - the last line.

Don't use a do/while, use a while()

```
while((rv = fscan(...)) != EOF) {
    printf(...);
}
```

That way, if fscanf fails, the printf is simply NOT executed.

do/while is basically "do the following at least once", while a `while` is "do the following zero-or-more times".